# SetSuspendState does not work with windows 10 supporting Standby S0 state

Tags: c++, windows, hibernate, msdn

I have a Windows 10 tablet with following PowerCfg states available,

- Standby (S0 Low Power Idle) network connected.
- Hibernate
- Fast Startup

In my C++ application, I am using [SetSuspendState function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373201(v=vs.85).aspx) with arguments (false, true, false) to make the Windows 10 tablet enter Sleep mode, but instead of entering Sleep mode the tablet Hibernates.

If I disable the Hibernate using 'PowerCfg /h off' then SetSuspendState call fails.

What is the correct API to send the Windows 10 tablet in Sleep mode?